# Display dynamic information in PowerView Report Title

Tags: powerview

I've a little problem, 
I've to display the refreshing date in the report title to be "My report title refreshed : Curent date for exemple" I think that the title is a statical object but our client needs this information.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  This is what I did.

Add a new sheet
In A1 add a Header (I called mine Title)
In A2 Add a formula that will display the title you want (I used this since I needed a dynamic title for the month ="This is for Month " & text(today(), "MMM")
Add this table to the data model
Add the Title field to the slide
I changed mine to a card and move to the title area.

Hope this gives you some thoughts on solving your issue

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with PowerView in Excel 2016. I have some data where the current week is important to some cells' formulas. I wanted to display my data in a better way so I used powerview, the thing is that Excel itself doesnt allow for table headers with formulas, so I took them out and made them static.

I added the formulas outside the headers so the rest of my data can still pull info from them.

The thing is, using 'Week1'...'Week5' can be confusing for my users since they work with weeks a lot, so they might think my report is from January/February of this year.

A workaround is adding labels with the correct weeks outside the charts, but I was wondering if there is a way to tie them to the cells where the week is updated so they can be updated in powerview, mainly vba through a macro.

Comment: You should delete this answer and add it as a new question. Try not to "piggy-back" old[er] questions, as you may never get a timely response.

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake, I saw this question while researching and I thought I opened a new tab to make a new question, apparently it was to make a comment. Sorry.